# Google maps application in iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application i added google maps application.It works fine.But in the map UI there is button zoomin and zoomout and also current location button, i want to hide or remove this button is this possible? i have load google map application in my UIWebview using this url @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=3711.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) and this [link](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) describe the parameters available to adjust the display of Google Maps.

However, you may be better off implementing [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205) instead of using a UIWebView. I would start by reading the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW1), and then looking at the projects listed under "Related sample code" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off to use the built-in framework MapKit.  It looks the exact same as Google Maps through the Web but all the controls are iPhone-native (pinch to zoom, scroll, etc).  The action is much smoother than on the Web.

Take a look at `MKMapView`.